# IOS Coredata compatible with both IOS 9 and ios 10

Tags: swift, core-data, ios9, ios10

Hi I'm developing an app to work with both IOS 10 and 9 (xcode 8). What is the proper way to create new entity object?

new IOS 10 has this code

```
var newEvent = Event(context: context)
```

How do we make this code work with both IOS 10 and 9?

I'm testing using Mater-Detail template with coredata xcode8

Any additional change should we make to ensure coredata work with both IOS 9 and 10? any help is much appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Basically Swift 3 is a giant pain in the backside if you want to target iOS earlier than iOS 10.  If this is what you want I would suggest using Swift 2.3 and backward compatibility.  If you are going to use Swift 3 then set your minimum deployment target to iOS 10 and cut off older iOS versions, otherwise you end up having to write the same code in two different ways everywhere bracketed with #if available ...

Comment: Hi I manage to make the CoreData path work for IOS 9 and 10. Only we need to use the older syntax for CoreData manipulation. Instead of using above code, I use let newEvent = Event(entity: NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Event", in: context)!, insertInto: context). But don't know it is the correct way to do or not

Comment: I have an question about multiple row deletion on IOS 10 also. Can help take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39696524/ios-10-nsfetchedresultcontroller-does-not-animate-when-deleting-multiple-rows