# IOS present Viewcontroller and pass data inside editActionsForRowAt

Tags: ios, tableview

Hi I'm developing an app with custom action in tableview cell.

when the user swipe the cell. There will be 2 action: delete and more. I want more action to present a new viewController and pass the object data to the new viewController. How do we achieve that?

I have tried using this

in `viewDidLoad`

```
if let split = self.splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            self.detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }
```

and `editActionsForRowAt` method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        let moreRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "More", handler:{action, indexpath in

            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let object = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
                let controller = self.detailViewController!
                controller.detailItem = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
                self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
//                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
        });
        moreRowAction.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.298, green: 0.851, blue: 0.3922, alpha: 1.0);

        let deleteRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler:{action, indexpath in
            self.deleteTapped(indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
        });

        return [deleteRowAction, moreRowAction];
    }
```

The delete function work but the more action does not work. And help is much appreciate! Thanks

[image]

My `prepareforseuge`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let object = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
                let controller = (segue.destination as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using storyboards? ie. do you want to segue to the new view controller? Or are you using NIB or programatic view controller creation? I see you have a commented segue, so I am guessing the former?

Comment: Hi yes. I have a segue from a tableviewCell label. Tried to use perform segue but the infomation is not passed to the new Viewcontroller. Info only pass when normal click (not in swipe edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your object via the `sender` parameter to your segue:

```
let moreRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "More", handler:{action, indexpath in
        let object = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: object)
    });
```

Then in `prepare(for segue: sender:)` -

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        guard let navVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
            let destVC = navVC.viewControllers.first as? DetailViewController else {
                return
        }

        var object = sender as? Event
        if object == nil {
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                object =  self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
            }
        }
        destVC.detailItem = object
    }
}
```

The Master-Detail template project uses a navigation controller as the detail destination, so the `prepare(for segue)` function needs to access the navigation controller's first view controller.

Also, since you are using the same segue for row tap and "more" actions, my code checks for both possibilities - the detail item could be in the sender or in the selected row

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I have added my prepare for segue in the question. The code from if let... is not call (may be it can not get the tableview.indexPathForselectedRow. If I move let obje... and self.perfomSegue.. outside. It can navigate to new viewcontroller but info is not pass (get nil on the variable of new viewController)

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh `moreRowAction ` block already have indexPath, why would you still `if let` it, just check if the data source got the data at that indexPath and `performSegue`, it doesn't call because you are not selecting it

Comment: Is the info did not pass to new Viewcontroller because segue is from tableview cell lable (set from storyboard).

Comment: Sorry, my answer included copy/pasted code that shouldn't be there.  You don't need to use `indexPathForSelectedRow`, the `indexPath` is already passed to the action closure.  In fact `indexPathForSelectedRow` won't work at all, since the action may occur on a row that isn't selected.

Comment: I can get the deletle action work. But not the more action. Data is not pass to new viecontroller. Iam using xcode 8 and the master detail template.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `prepare(for segue)` and step through.  Why isn't the data being sent?  Have you updated your `action` closure after I deleted my error?  Did you subsitute `YourObjectClass` to the appropriate class for `detailItem`?

Comment: Hi I set a break point . prepare for segue is called when more action click but seem indexpathforselectedRow notworking. My segue when click label (from tableviewCell) is working normally

Comment: I add NSLog((object.timestamp?.description)!) after let object.. inside editActionsrow and can get result 2016-09-25 18:50:12 +0000 on the log but get nil when come to new Viewcontroller

Comment: Step through the `prepare(for segue)` - what is happening there.  Learn how to use the Xcode debugger - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/UsingtheDebugger.html It is a very powerful tool

Comment: when click more action, step to if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow { (from prepare for segue) using debugger step through. debugger step to end of the if let (may be the if let for prepare for segue is false and not get execute those code inside)

Comment: I think self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow become nill when preparesegue is called (more action click)

Comment: Yes, don't use `indexPathForSelectedRow` - refer to the code in my answer. It doesn't use this.

Comment: Use exactly same code from your answer but still get nil on the new ViewController. I'm using xcode 8 Master-Detail template. Can try?

Comment: Thanks it work flawlessly! The trick is the navigation part? Are you author of Hackingwithswift.com. I learn a lot from these project, truely my hero

Comment: Nope, not the author of anything

Comment: Much appreciate! can help with this new coreData question on IOS 10 and 9? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39687249/ios-coredata-compatible-with-both-ios-9-and-ios-10